# Need help splitting a string thats being passed into a function in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on some code right now but am unable to do accomplish this task. The objective is to take a string that is passed through a function.
Example function:

```
void function(string line1, string line2, string line3)
```

A string will be entered from the main function and it'll be passed into the first parameter "line1". The job of this function will be to "split the string to the closest whitespace character and put the first part of the string in line2, and the rest in line3.

For example if the string passed into line1 was:

```
"Good Job"
```

I have to write some code that will split this string and assign each part to lines 2 and 3 so line2 = Good and line3 = Job.

Comment: Split in half (at the closest whitespace) or at the first whitespace?  That example is very vague.  For example `Good Job Bill`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). Modify your function to accept the last two parameters by reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
void function(const std::string& line1, std::string& line2, std::string& line3){
    std::stringstream ss(line1);
    ss >> line2 >> line3; // the space character acts as a delimiter
}
int main(){
    std::string s2, s3;
    function("Good Job", s2, s3);
    std::cout << s2 << ' ' << s3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ron has given a good solution using `std::stringstream` here's an alternate sol using `find` and `substr`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void function(string line1, string& line2, string& line3)
{
  std::size_t found = line1.find(" ");
  if (found!=std::string::npos){
      line2 = line1.substr(0,found);
      line3 = line1.substr(found+1);
  }
}

int main() {
  string line1 = "Good Day";
  string line2, line3;
  function(line1, line2, line3);
  cout <<line1<<endl;
  cout <<line2<<endl;
  cout <<line3<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
Good Day
Good
Day
```

Comment: @Tas: Corrected!